# Phase Shift Of Operational Amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, gain, inverting-amplifier

From the datasheet the open loop phase shift is given as 90 degrees for a range of frequency.
But why doesn't a a normal open loop inverting amplifier does not show this characteristics of the phase shift of 90 degree.Instead it just inverts the output(Or say 180 degree phase shift).

[image]

What happened to the phase shift given by a Op amp?
[image]

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/352391/individual-phase-shift-provided-by-op-amp-in-closed-loop-configuration

Answer (score 0):

The first figure is open loop response, which means the bandwidth and phase are determined by the amplifier alone.

The second figure is a closed loop response, which is determined by the amplifier and the gain of the feedback loop. The closed loop response will usually be lower bandwidth. The phase shift is determined by the pole of the closed loop system, which in the case of the closed loop graph, is at 10Hz.